# FROALA non editable content

Tags: froala

I am building an email template with FROALA. 
I don't want to give the user the power to edit a part of it. 
Is there a way to stop the user from editing a part of the content?

Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

The best way for that would be to use the `contenteditable=false` flag and there is an example on the Froala Github repo as well: https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/blob/master/html/popular/disable_edit.html#L40.

```
<p>This <span contenteditable="false">zone</span> can't be edited.</p>
```

If you would like to allow deleting that when using backspace/delete, then you should also add the class `fr-deletable` to it:

```
<p>This <span contenteditable="false" class="fr-deletable">zone</span> can be deleted.</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

For that, You can use

```
<div contenteditable="false"></div>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Froala allows you to make froala non-editable,

Lets make this instance non editable:

```
<div id="froala-editor"></div>
```

Initiate Froala Instance:

```
$('#froala-editor').froalaEditor({});
```

Make in non-editable

```
$('#froala-editor').froalaEditor('edit.off');
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q87duk2c/17/

[image]

If you want to activate it again you can do:

```
$('#froala-editor').froalaEditor('edit.on');
```

Answer (score 0):

Requirement can be of 2 types :

1. As soon as we initiate froala editor we want editor to be disabled in that particular scenario below code will work.

HTML:

```
<div id="froala-editor">

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#froala-editor').froalaEditor({});
$('#froala-editor').froalaEditor('edit.off');
```

2. If we want some part of html to be in read only mode will other must work as editable.For that

```
<div id="froala-editor">
<div id="new" contenteditable="false">
  <p>
  hi lets make this content non editable
  </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**contenteditable=false just give this attribute on top of it.**

div with id new is in **read only** mode.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I need to disable/enable the toolbar too (only in this case the cursor is correct when moving the mouse above any button in the toolbar):

```
var editor = new FroalaEditor(...);
...
if (booReadOnly) {
    editor.edit.off();
    editor.toolbar.disable();
} else {
    editor.edit.on();
    editor.toolbar.enable();
```

}